# Spring Joining table insert. Skip adding records to other table in join. Persist data only to main and link table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Help me in Entity design with the for following E-R.

[image]

Here I need to insert entries into REQUEST table and REQ_TYPE_MAP table. There shouldn't be any entry to TYPE_MAST table.
TYPE_MAST contains master data that are loaded once. I need to map the master data to a request.

But the below approach that I use had adding entries to TYPE_MAST table too. How can I avoid that.

### Request Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REQUEST")
public class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="REQUEST_ID")
    private long requestId;

    @Column(name="CIVILID")
    private Long civilId;

    @Column(name="MOBILE_NO")
    private Long mobileNo;

    @ManyToMany(cascade ={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="REQ_TYPE_MAP", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID")
    )
private Set<MsaDisabScreenRequest> disabilities= new HashSet<MsaDisabScreenRequest>()

    /**
        getters & setters
        equals() & hashCode()
    **/
}
```

### Type Mast Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TYPE_MAST")
public class MsaDisabMaster implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="TYPE_ID")
    private long disTypeId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    /**
        getters & setters
        equals() & hashCode()
    **/

}
```

### Request DTO

```
  public class RequestDto implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        

        private long requestId; 

        private Long civilId;    

        private Long mobileNo;      

private Set<MsaDisabScreenRequestDto> disabilities= new HashSet<MsaDisabScreenRequestDto>()

        /**
            getters & setters
            equals() & hashCode()
        **/
    }
```

### Type Mast Dto

```
public class MsaDisabMasterDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long disTypeId;

    private String name;

    /**
        getters & setters
        equals() & hashCode()
    **/

}
```

Using spring JPA to persist.

**@Service** code relevant to save(let me know if you required more details).

```
   Service
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class ReqServiceImpl implements ReqService {

    @Autowired
    MsaRepository msaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OrikaBeanMapper mapper;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackOn = BusinessException.class)
    public long saveScreeningRequest(RequestDto requestDto) throws BusinessException {


        try {
            // mapping
            Request request = mapper.map(requestDto,Request.class);

            Request res = reqRepository.save(request);
            if (msaDisabScreenRes != null) {
                return res.getRequestId();
            } else {
                //throw exception
            }
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            //throw exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide you service code...

Comment: @Cepr0 question updated.

Comment: And please provide the the declaration of `MsaDisabMaster` reference in `Request`, it's missed. And show `RequestDto` as well.

Comment: @Cepr0 updated the question, added dto.

Comment: What about `MsaDisabMaster` reference in `Request`? )

Comment: @Cepr0 that too added.. I missed code formatting.

Comment: I updated my answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173448/discussion-between-user630209-and-cepr0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since `MsaDisabMaster` is a permanent data, I recommend to make it [immutable](https://vladmihalcea.com/immutable-entity-jpa-hibernate/).

As `MsaDisabMaster` objects are already persisted then you must **remove** cascading from its reference in `Request`.

In your service you should 'attach' all `MsaDisabMaster` that are contained in `RequestDto` to the resulted `Request`. You can do this with `getOne` method of your `MsaDisabMaster` repository, something like this:

```
requestDto.getDisabilities()
    .forEach(m -> request.getDisabilities().add(msaDisabMasterRepo.getOne(m.getDisTypeId())));
```

Then you can save request using `save()` method of the `Request` repository.

Comment: As MsaDisabMaster objects are already persisted then you must remove cascading from its reference in Request. - This is solved the problem. Haven't followed the below steps.

Comment: OK. Then check your hibernate logs - does it make redundant select queries for 'disabilities'?..

Comment: @user630209 please check the fresh [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/) of Vlad Mihalcea related to this topic (`getReference` method is used in `getOne` method)

Comment: checked the logs there is no redundant select queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example:
https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

This should work for you

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.PERSIST, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "REQ_TYPE_MAP",joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_ID", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
```

Comment: Not working, it still trying to persist data into TYPE_MAST table.